master-detail: modify all rows in detail table on click of master row
I've created a master-detail page in Oracle APEX with the master table st_training_details, where t_id is the primary key, and the detail table st_tni_master, where tni_details references t_id as a foreign key. I added a new column in the Page Designer for st_training_details as a checkbox. When the user clicks this checkbox, the t_id of the selected row should be stored in the tni_details column of all rows in st_tni_master. I've only created the checkbox so far and need assistance with implementing the functionality to store the t_id in tni_details. Please provide a detailed, step-by-step explanation to complete this setup.
I tried by passing report data to page items and then from page item to required column. but this is not working.

From your description, it seems a checkbox is not what you need. A checkbox typically does not have any action until a page is submitted (unless that is what you want). If an immediate action is needed, use a button.
By default, master detail creates interactive grid regions. Those are harder to customize because a lot more client side javascript is needed.

If an interactive report is a region for both reports then you could have a look at some of my other answers that describe how to create a button in an interactive report that is bound to a dynamic action

Please provide  me any solution for the situation i descried..
